# vba code for selecting columns defined names

Tags: vba, excel

So i am working on a macro but got stuck trying to figure out how something (i initially believe was simple) turned out to be very difficult.

I am having trouble with the vba code to select columns with defined names.

I believe the generic code to select entire columns is just like the below:

```
Columns("T:U").Select
```

but in my case, the columns I want to select are dynamically defined as "`wap`" and "`awap`".  Specifically `wap = T` and `awap = U` to keep things simple.

So, finally, why does neither of the below work?

```
Columns("wap:awap").Select

Columns(wap:awap).Select
```

Can someone show me the correct syntax/code to select columns wap and awap?  Thank you!!

Comment: Try: `Dim wap As String : wap = "T" Dim awap As String : awap = "U" Columns(wap & ":" & awap).Select`

Comment: Have you defined the wap and awap As Range? It might help if we can see where you defined your variables.

Comment: And don't use Select if possible. Maybe you can get away with With

Comment: Thank you Maciej...Columns(wap & ":" & awap).Select works.

Answer (score 1):

If wap and awap are defined as named ranges, then you could use `Range("wap:awap").select`.

If wap and awap are strings, with a letter indicating a column, you could concatenate the strings into a range - `Range(wap & ":" & awap)`